# Unemployment and minimum wage data by state (US)?

Tags: data-request, usa

Where can I find yearly (historical) unemployment and minimum wage data (preferably inflation adjusted) by state?

I've checked BLS and DOL but they are not very user friendly for statistical analyses.

Comment: Maybe this is fixed by now: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9988/minimum-wage-data-via-dol-api

Comment: Possible helpful links here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6576/how-can-i-find-state-level-data-on-the-unemployment-rate-of-youth-for-2014-and-2  It's not exactly a duplicate of your question, because you ask for unemployment data as well. Hint: Next time make this two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

FRED has unemployment statistics for states:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/tags/series?t=state%3Bunemployment&ob=pv&od=desc